# while loop not printing message

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

The program is a game where the user has to guess the magical number to win. I'm new to java, and I am still learning. When I type in 53, it just ask the question agains instead of displaying the output. I'm sure it's a simple error that I'm just not catching. Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
class NumberFrom1To100 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean stillplaying = true;
        double answer = 53;
        double userAnswer;
        String userInput;

        while (stillplaying == true) {

            userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a number between 1 and 100.");
            userAnswer = Double.parseDouble(userInput);

            while (userAnswer != 53) {
                if (userAnswer < 53) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked a number LESS than the mystery number. Try again.");
                    break;
                } else if (userAnswer > 53) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked a number GREATER than the mystery number. Try again.");
                    break;
                } else if (userAnswer == 53) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations! You just won 5 brownie points!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        /* System.exit(0); */
    }
}
```

Comment: while(stillplaying) is fine don't need == true you dont need the another while loop...

Comment: Why are you using a `double` for storing the answer?

Comment: set still playing to false when userAnswer is 53 and can remove the while (userAnswer !=53).

Comment: `while (userAnswer != 53) {` is not needed here

Comment: You don't need the inner while loop             while (userAnswer != 53) {
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner while loop is not only not needed, it is also breaking your program. Two scenarios, either `userAnswer` is `53` or not. Let's check those two scenarios.

Not equal to `53` will trigger the while loop. If it is less than, equal to (which it never can be), or greater than `53` it will break. Which renders a loop obsolete.

Equal to `53` won't trigger the loop at all, which is the result you are experiencing now.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class NumberFrom1To100
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean stillplaying = true;
        double answer = 53;
        double userAnswer;
        String userInput;

        while (stillplaying) {
            userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a number between 1 and 100.");
            userAnswer = Double.parseDouble(userInput);

            if (userAnswer < 53) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked a number LESS than the mystery number. Try again.");
            } else if (userAnswer > 53) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked a number GREATER than the mystery number. Try again.");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations! You just won 5 brownie points!");
            }
        }

        // System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

*I do not know how you want to handle "victory", you can set `stillplaying` to `false` in that comparison.*

I also took the liberity of removing your comparison to `true` in the outer `while` loop as it does nothing. It is also common to name the variable with lowerCamelCase => `stillPlaying` which could only be called `playing`, a fairly common name of the `boolean`-game loop variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

else if (userAnswer == 53) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations! You just won 5 brownie points!");

will never be reached because you have put it inside

while (userAnswer != 53) {.....}

Just remove this inner while loop with it's respective parentheses and it should be good.

Correct code will be:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

class NumberFrom1To100 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    boolean stillplaying = true;
    double answer = 53;
    double userAnswer;
    String userInput;

    while (stillplaying == true) {

        userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a number between 1 and 100.");
        userAnswer = Double.parseDouble(userInput);


            if (userAnswer < 53) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked a number LESS than the mystery number. Try again.");

            } else if (userAnswer > 53) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You picked a number GREATER than the mystery number. Try again.");

            } else if (userAnswer == 53) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations! You just won 5 brownie points!");

            }

    }``
    /* System.exit(0); */
}
```

}

Comment: The `break`s in the `if` statements will quite literally break the application. You also have some formatting problems in the answer.